# I'm trying to multiply all numerical data in a dataset of crimes by different numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a dataset of crimes and i'm trying to multiply them by multipliers ive created for each crime. eg homicide has a multiplier of 1 but violence without injury has a multiplier of 0.1 as it is less severe. I'm also trying to create a new dataset with the multiplied data but the line of code I've used didn't work because I think the column of names of counties was trying to be multiplied by something  but as they aren't numerical it failed

I tried this:

```
Scored_Data = mydatas.mul({
    'Homicide': 'Homicide_multi',
    'Violence_against_the_person': 'Violence_against_the_person_multi',
    'Area_Name': 1,
    'Violence_with_injury': 'Violence_with_injury_multi',
    'Violence_without_injury': 'Violence_without_injury_multi',
    'Criminal_damage_and_arson': 'Criminal_damage_and_arson_multi',
    'Possession_of_weapons_offences': 'Possession_of_weapons_offences_multi',
   'Population_100000': 1
})
```

I've already assigned values to the _multi values.

Comment: Can you provide the output of `print(mydatas.head().to_dict())` please?

Comment: "ive already assigned values to the _multi values" - how did you do this? these are assigned as scalars? in which case, do not use quotes around the scalars in the .mul command.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Making an assumption that your dataframe looks similar to this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"Crime": ["Homicide", "Violence without injury",
                             "Possession of weapons offences", "Homicide"],
                   "County": ["Suffolk", "Kent", "Devon", "Kent"],
                   "Num 1": [100, 90, 80, 30], "Num 2": [34, 24, 56, 75]})
#                            Crime   County  Num 1  Num 2
#0                        Homicide  Suffolk    100     34
#1         Violence without injury     Kent     90     24
#2  Possession of weapons offences    Devon     80     56
#3                        Homicide     Kent     30     75
```

You could create a dictionary of the multiples you want to use and multiply the selected columns of numerical data by mapping the correct rows:

```py
homicide_multi = 1
violence_without_injury_multi = 0.1
possession_of_weapons_offences_multi = 0.7

map_dict = {"Homicide": homicide_multi,
            "Violence without injury": violence_without_injury_multi,
            "Possession of weapons offences": possession_of_weapons_offences_multi}


# multiply with mapping
df[["Num 1", "Num 2"]].mul(df["Crime"].map(map_dict), axis=0)

# create new dataframe with new data.
Scored_Data = df.copy()
Scored_Data[["Num 1", "Num 2"]] = df[["Num 1", "Num 2"]].mul(
    df["Crime"].map(map_dict), axis=0)

# output
Scored_Data
#                            Crime   County  Num 1  Num 2
#0                        Homicide  Suffolk  100.0   34.0
#1         Violence without injury     Kent    9.0    2.4
#2  Possession of weapons offences    Devon   56.0   39.2
#3                        Homicide     Kent   30.0   75.0
```

Hopefully this helps, even if your data is in a different format.